# mongodb query using 2 $near operator. Find users near start and destination location

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I have a problem where I need to locate users at a source and aggregate them according to their destination locations. I tried using multiple $near queries as listed below:

```
db.getCollection('user_requests').find({"destGeoLoc":$near:{$geometry: {$type:"Point", coordinates:77.2432720999999987,28.5676954999999992]},$maxDistance:2000}},"sourceGeoLoc":{$near:$geometry: {$type:"Point",coordinates:77.2219549999999941,28.6423729999999992]},$maxDistance:2000}}, "match_status" : "no" })
```

It gave a following error:

```
error: {
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Too many geoNear expressions",
"code" : 17287
```

}

Now I understand the error itself, but I seem to have run into a roadblock as to how to get past this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution by posting two separate $near queries at both source and destination, and taking a set intersection of ObjectId. It's crude, but works.